# Is FEC-code needed for UDP?

Tags: udp

I received this reply on the Live555-mailing list:
"FEC is not needed for UDP.    The UDP service delivers a packet, or does not.
UDP does not randomly flip some bits inside the packet.
To tolerate packet loss, only redundancy is needed."

I would like to know if this statement is correct; and please also provide the sources on which your answer are based.

Clarification: I was referring to Forward Erasure Correction. Maybe the person answering in the Live555-list was referring to Forward Error Code.

Comment: It's true enough that UDP doesn't randomly flip bits inside the packet, but it's quite possible for bits to be randomly flipped as the packet traverses the network.  Note that the UDP checksum, if it's even enabled, is 16-bit one's complement (not as good as a CRC for certain types of data mangling, and there's a 1 in 2**16 chance that a random mangling will not be detected by the checksum).

Comment: In the video broadcasting world, _FEC_ does stand for _Forward Error Correction_, and they mean by that adding error correcting packets to a stream (generally UDP) to correct for packet loss in a real-time context (thus, TCP is generally not useful). Look for SMPTE ST 2022-1 for one such standard, also draft-ietf-payload-flexible-fec-scheme-06 for another.  (Yes indeed, other groups call this _Forward Erasure Correction_.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDP in itself does nothing to cause or prevent bits being flipped. Depending on how the data is transmitted, bits being flipped is certainly possible.

At the same time, most networking has moved toward error correction taking place at a lower level in the stack, so in a lot of cases, you can probably get by without adding any as a layer on top of UDP. That, however, is far from guaranteed -- depending on the physical layer over which you transmit it, bit errors in UDP packets certainly remain a possibility, so if you really need to ensure against that, independent of the lower layers in use, then FEC could provide real utility.

Edit: and yes, I'd guess that absent some context to indicate otherwise, most people using "FEC" mean "forward error correction" (that's certainly what I thought you were referring to when I wrote the reply).

Answer (score 0):

IP packets have got checksums in the headers. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4), [RFC791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791), etc.

Whether that is good enough for your application is for you to decide.

Answer (score 0):

inside UDP stack there is no FEC correction, just a checksum calculation to see whether received datagram has wrong bits inside, if yes, that packet will be discarded. To apply FEC to transport channel using UDP it is generallly to use reed-solomon code. In wired network the possibility of wrong bit inside packet is very low, but in wireless network is pretty high, therefore, the wirelless links provide all FEC such as turo-code to correct data symbol ( number of bits ) inside datalink packets.

Steven